# Android studio debug on breakpoint does not work

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developping application and have some errors. İ added breakpoints and debug does not work. In some code, says

> no executable code found

in others there is only tick on breakpoint.

what is wrong with Android Studio

My android-studio version:1.2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem running the debugger on an emulator and I simply tried using a different one and it worked. I know some phones having problems running the debugger

http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/android-studio-does-not-stop-on-some-breakpoints-when-connected-to-samsung-galaxy-s5-with-lollipop-5/202/277622?boardName=General&startId=zzzzz~

Hope this helps!